# Pyplot in Jupyter Lab inline - cropped image?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I have the following code, which should add a 30% margin on the left:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6,6), facecolor="#dddddd")
plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.plot(range(10), range(10))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.3)
plt.savefig('example.png')
```

The output png does indeed have the margin, but the inline image in jupyter lab does not. Is there a fix for this?

example.png:

[image: Output png with margin]

Screenshot from jupyter lab:

[image: Inline image with margin cropped]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inline backend has its own parameters and it sets `bbox_inches` to `'tight'` by default, see [source](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/aba2179420a3fa81ee6b8a13f928bf9e5ce50716/ipykernel/pylab/config.py#L83).
So you need to revert this default setting by

```
%config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs={'bbox_inches': None}
```

[image]